# Enable application logging in web app using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, azure-powershell, azure-web-app-service

Can I enable the application logging in a web app using PowerShell?

Currently, I run these commands to enable other settings but I cannot figure out how to enable the application log (File System) setting.

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "habdol" -DetailedErrorLoggingEnabled $true -HttpLoggingEnabled $true -RequestTracingEnabled $true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Enable-AzureWebsiteapplicationDiagnostic` cmdlet.  For example, to set application logging (file system) at the *Warning* level, do the following:

```
Enable-AzureWebsiteApplicationDiagnostic -Name $webAppName -File -LogLevel Warning
```

Note, there is not an "AzureRM" equivalent cmdlet for this.  At least not that I've seen.

Also, remember that when you enable application logging to the file system, it will automatically disable after 12 hours.

Comment: I am using the AzureRM cmdlet so I am not able to do that.